# Can projects in SSISDB only be moved manually?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Deploying SSISDB projects between Dev and Test servers is currently a manual process for me. Is there a way to script that process or otherwise automate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Integration Services Deployment Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017#integration-services-deployment-wizard)

The wizard also allows you to create a [command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-deploy-cmdline?view=sql-server-2017) which can be used to automate the deployment.

[image]

The second link, which is quickstart sample shows other ways to automate the deployment.